# Problems with grid content on display:grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My first time working with 'display: grid', I had trouble inserting content into one of the grids.

What happens? When assembling the grids, everything is very beautiful and the way I need, but when I insert text inside one of them, it lengthens and loses the entire layout. Why does this happen and how to prevent it?

```css
.agrupou-a-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  'a a b' 
  'c d b' 
  'e f f' 
  'g g h' 
  'i j j';
}

.agrupou-a-grid .box {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="agrupou-a-grid">
  <div class="box gd1">
    <div class="group-content">
      <h2>Coleção em destaque</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box gd2"></div>
  <div class="box gd3"></div>
  <div class="box gd4"></div>
  <div class="box gd5"></div>
  <div class="box gd6"></div>
  <div class="box gd7"></div>
  <div class="box gd8"></div>
  <div class="box gd9"></div>
  <div class="box gd10"></div>
</div>
```

Before placing text

[image]

After placing text

[image]

Comment: You're experiencing **overflow** because you have limited the rows to 50px. What did you expect to happen? Also your CSS is incomplete.

Comment: You're right, but the main problem is in the columns and not in the rows, but with your observation I came to realize that!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, the resolution was to put a `grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;` since the grid has 3 columns. Very obvious, I know.

Comment: you should use `1fr 1fr 1fr` instead and not `33%`